# Format Range as Currency - Excel Javascript

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I'm trying to format a cell as Currency via Excel JavaScript API. I've tried `currency` and `$` but neither work.

What do I need to do?

```
var Rev_Rng = ws.getRangeByIndexes(2, Header_Arr.indexOf("Est. Revenue"), Used_Rng_And_Props.rowCount - 2, 1)
Rev_Rng.select()
await context.sync()
Rev_Rng.numberFormat = '$'; //This just inserted '$' as the value I also tried 'currency'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use something like that for the currency format:

```
"$#,###.00"
```

See [Number format codes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) for more information.